# Error en libstdc++-6.dll al ejecutar programa de c++

Tags: c++, dll

Estoy comenzando a programar en c++ y bien, estaba haciendo un programa simple de numeros pares y resulta que al ejecutar el código me muestra ese error, alguien me ayuda? El código es:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)

{
    float kilometros = 0;

    float precio = 0;

    float bs = 0;
    
    printf("\nIngrese el numero de kilometros: ");
    scanf("%f", &kilometros);
    printf("\n Ingrese el precio por kilometro: ");
    scanf("%f",&bs);
    precio = kilometros * bs;
    printf("\n El precio del boleto es de Bs. %.2f\n",precio);
    
    system("PAUSE");
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error? ¿Qué código?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ya agregué el código, en  DEV c++ me compila bien, pero cuando lo intento usar en Visual Studio o usando un editor de texto me lanza ese error